# Setting an NSDate to always use midnight

Tags: swift, nsdate

Right now I set an NSDate object like so:

```
func userSelectedDate(selectedDate : NSDate) {
    let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy"
    let dateString = formatter.stringFromDate(selectedDate)
}
```

I always want to use midnight though. How do I force the usage of a certain time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
let dateAtMidnight = calendar.startOfDayForDate(NSDate())
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a<strike>n app</strike> method for that

```
let startOfSelectedDate = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().startOfDayForDate(selectedDate)
```